# I can't upload some images in php

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I tried upload images. Some images not be able to upload. It shows successfully uploaded but doesn't goes to the folder and database. Below is my code

```
            // Count total files
            $countfiles = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

            // Prepared statement
            $query = "INSERT INTO images_list (name,location,sys_album_id) 
            VALUES (?,?,'".$_POST["albumid"]."')";
            $statement  = $conn->prepare($query);

            // Loop all files
            for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){

            // File name
            $strtotime = strtotime("now");
            $filename = $strtotime.'_'.$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $albumid = $_POST['albumid'];

            // Get extension
            $ext = end((explode(".", $filename)));

            // Valid image extension
            $valid_ext = array("png","jpeg","jpg");

            if(in_array($ext, $valid_ext)){

            $rawBaseName = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
            $extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
            $counter = 0;
            while(file_exists("filer/".$albumid."/".$name)) {
            $fname = $rawBaseName . $counter . '.' . $extension;
            $counter++;
            };
```

Comment: Only some of them? Are the file sizes on those larger than the others?

Comment: Yes, The images failed to upload are larger than 2MB. Images which lesser than 2MB can be uploaded successfully.

Comment: Then you will need to make changes to allow files sizes larger than 2MB to PHP in the php.ini

Comment: How shall I do it? Sorry I am new to PHP. Should i create a new file call php.ini?

Comment: No, you should already have one on your web server. Find it, edit it, then restart your webserver as shown in the question I linked to above.

Comment: The issue i am facing right now, I can upload single image with large size but I can't upload multi images with large size